# Convert an output to string

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I'm trying do to a script to check the CA power status

this is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

a=$(acpitool -a)

echo "$a"

if $a -eq "AC adapter : online"
then
echo "ONLINE"
else
echo "OFFLINE"
fi
```

It's not working; the variable `$a` ia not compare with the the string "AC adapter : online". How to convert the output of command `acpitool -a` to a string?

This is what happens:

```
AC adapter     : online 
./acpower.sh: linha 7: AC: comando não encontrado
OFFLINE
```

**Problem solved!**

This is the new code, whith the help of all of you, thanks.

```
#!/bin/bash

# set the variable
a=$(acpitool -a)

# remove white spaces
a=${a// /}

# echo for test
echo $a

# compare the result
if [[ "$a" == 'ACadapter:online' ]]
then
# then that the imagination is the limit
echo "ONLINE"
else
# else if you have no imagination you're lost
echo "OFFLINE"
fi
```

This code may be use on a server, to alert if the power fails!

Comment: How about putting $a in quotes when comparing? like: if "$a" -eq "AC adapter : online"?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  You did a nice job on your question; you showed the code, you explained what you wanted and what you got as an error — all good technique.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### How to fix the problem

The shell (or the `test` command) uses `=` for string equality and `-eq` for numeric equality.  Some versions of the shell support `==` as a synonym for `=` (but `=` is defined by the POSIX [`test`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) command).  By contrast, Perl uses `==` for numeric equality and `eq` for string equality.

You also need to use one of the test commands:

```
if [ "$a" = "AC adapter : online" ]
then echo "ONLINE"
else echo "OFFLINE"
fi
```

Or:

```
if [[ "$a" = "AC adapter : online" ]]
then echo "ONLINE"
else echo "OFFLINE"
fi
```

With the `[[` operator, you could drop the quotes around `"$a"`.

#### Why you got the error message

When you wrote:

```
if $a -eq "AC adapter : online"
```

the shell expanded it to:

```
if AC adapter : online -eq "AC adapter : online"
```

which is a request to execute the command `AC` with the 5 arguments shown, and compare the exit status of the command with 0 (considering 0 — success — as true and anything non-zero as false).  Clearly, you don't have a command called `AC` on your system (which is not very surprising).

This means you can write:

```
if grep -q -e 'some.complex*pattern' $files
then echo The pattern was found in some of the files
else echo The pattern was not found in any of the files
fi
```

If you want to test strings, you have to use the `test` command or the `[[ ... ]]` operator.  The `test` command is the same as the `[` command except that when the command name is `[`, the last argument must be `]`.

Answer (score 3):

Please try this -

```
    #!/bin/bash
    a="$(acpitool -a)"

    echo "$a"

    if [ "$a" == 'AC adapter : online' ]
    then
    echo "ONLINE"
    else
    echo "OFFLINE"
    fi
```

**Explanation:** `-eq` is mainly used for equivalence for integer expressions. So, == is the way to go! And, use double quotes across $a or $(acpitool -a) to prevent word splitting. An argument enclosed within double quotes presents itself as a single word, even if it contains whitespace separators.

Comment: That will solve the problem(s), but your answer would be improved if you explained why.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I hope it's better now. Many thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Yes, it is better.  You didn't (yet) note that you added the test command to the `if` statement.  :)  Just picking nits.

Comment: He can figure that out, I guess :) And you answer sufficiently answers that I suppose. So, I won't worry much :)

Answer (score 3):

Put the comparision in square brackets and add double quotes around the `$a`:

```
if [ "$a" == "AC adapter : online" ]; then
  ...
```

Without the square brackets `bash` tries to execute the expression and evaluate the return value.

It may also be a good idea to put the command substitution in double quotes:

```
a="$(acpitool -a)"
```

Comment: The double quotes around `a="$(acpitool -a)"` are not necessary, though they do no harm — unless the command needs double-quoted arguments, in which case the outer double quotes complicate things to the extent that it is much better to drop them.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler No, they don't. Command substitution with `$()` differs from command substitution with `\`\`` in this respect. Something like `a="$(echo "foo bar")"` will work just fine.

Comment: Ugh...ISTR coming across this recently, and you're right about `a="$(echo "a ")"` working OK.  It confuses the hell out of me so I'd not do it, but I learned shell coding in shells where it really did matter (ones which didn't have `$(...)` at all — it hadn't been invented yet), so I tend to be old-fashioned.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved!

This is the new code, whith the help of all of you, thanks.

```
#!/bin/bash

# set the variable
a=$(acpitool -a)

# remove white spaces
a=${a// /}

# echo for test
echo $a

# compare the result
if [[ "$a" == 'ACadapter:online' ]]
then
# then that the imagination is the limit
echo "ONLINE"
else
# else if you have no imagination you're lost
echo "OFFLINE"
fi
```

This code may be use on a server, to alert if the power fails!